# Wrong SUM calculations in OLAP cube

Tags: ssas, olap, olap-cube, dimension

I'm pretty new to SSAS and i have encountered a quite odd issue. The simple SUM function in OLAP cube shows wrong numbers based on the dimension usage.

I have created simple OLAP cube in SSAS, which tracks fuel payments across company car fleet. Data source is a SQL database server, and I use table "purchase" (contains information of amount of fuel bought, paid price, location of purchase etc.) as a measure and tables "car" (information about car type, its registration ID etc.), "location" (plant location the driver originates from) and "division" as dimensions.

When I first connected all dimensions to the measure on the "Dimension usage" tab, I got wrong sum of the price paid and amount of fuel bought - the sum displayed was much lower than the actual one. I tried to look into it and the numbers were wrong as well if i looked at the data by division, location etc.

But when I used the "Car" dimension and created table showing the data for each individual car, the results were correct, which I find weird.

When I disconnected the "Car" dimension from the measure group, the totals in the cube were correct, but i was (of course) unable to look at individual numbers for each car.

I understand that there is some problem with the "Car" dimension, but I am unable to find out what exactly goes wrong. Any advice helping me to identify where to look would be much appreciated. Thanks in advance.